# how can I make a custom carousel or image slide in react native without using any npm packages

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I am making a custom image carousel or an image slider in react native without using any packages, the issue is that the dot indicators on the bottom are changing fine after 3 second intervals but the image doesn't slides automatically. There is some minor issue which I am unable to find. If you can help in getting this fixed without changing much of the code it would be really nice. thanks in advance.

Here is the full component code.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Dimensions, Text} from 'react-native';
import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import {Image} from 'react-native-elements';

const HomeCarousel = () => {
  const [dimension, setDimension] = useState(Dimensions.get('window'));
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

  const scrollRef = useRef();

  const onChange = () => {
    setDimension(Dimensions.get('window'));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', onChange);
    return () => {
      Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', onChange);
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setSelectedIndex(prevSelectedIndex =>
        prevSelectedIndex === carouselImages.length - 1
          ? 0
          : prevSelectedIndex + 1,
      );
      () => {
        scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
          animated: true,
          y: 0,
          x: dimension.width * selectedIndex,
        });
      };
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  const carouselImages = [
    {url: 'https://i.ibb.co/FDwNR9d/img1.jpg'},
    {url: 'https://i.ibb.co/7G5qqGY/1.jpg'},
    {url: 'https://i.ibb.co/Jx7xqf4/pexels-august-de-richelieu-4427816.jpg'},
    {url: 'https://i.ibb.co/GV08J9f/pexels-pixabay-267202.jpg'},
    {url: 'https://i.ibb.co/sK92ZhC/pexels-karolina-grabowska-4210860.jpg'},
  ];

  const setIndex = event => {
    let viewSize = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width;
    let contentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    let carouselIndex = Math.floor(contentOffset / viewSize);
    setSelectedIndex(carouselIndex);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{width: dimension.width}}>
      <ScrollView
        horizontal
        ref={scrollRef}
        onMomentumScrollEnd={setIndex}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        pagingEnabled>
        {carouselImages.map((value, key) => (
          <Image
            source={{uri: `${value.url}`}}
            style={{width: dimension?.width, height: 250, resizeMode: 'cover'}}
            PlaceholderContent={<ActivityIndicator />}
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0,
          alignSelf: 'center',
        }}>
        {carouselImages.map((val, key) => (
          <Text
            key={key}
            style={key === selectedIndex ? {color: 'white'} : {color: '#888'}}>
            ⬤
          </Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default HomeCarousel;
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the full working code.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Dimensions, Text} from 'react-native';
import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import {Image} from 'react-native-elements';

const HomeCarousel = () => {
  const [dimension, setDimension] = useState(Dimensions.get('window'));
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

  const scrollRef = useRef();
  let intervalId = null;

  const onChange = () => {
    setDimension(Dimensions.get('window'));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', onChange);
    return () => {
      Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', onChange);
    };
  });

  const onSlideChange = useCallback(() => {
    // Calculate newIndex here and use it to update your state and to scroll to the new slide
    const newIndex =
      selectedIndex === carouselImages.length - 1 ? 0 : selectedIndex + 1;

    setSelectedIndex(newIndex);

    scrollRef?.current?.scrollTo({
      animated: true,
      y: 0,
      x: dimension.width * newIndex,
    });
  }, [selectedIndex]);

  const startInterval = useCallback(() => {
    intervalId = setInterval(onSlideChange, 3000);
  }, [onSlideChange]);

  useEffect(() => {
    startInterval();

    return () => {
      // Clear the interval when component unmounts, otherwise you could have memory leaks
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, [onSlideChange]);

  const onTouchStart = () => {
    // As soon as the user touches the slide, stop the automatic sliding
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  };

  const onTouchEnd = () => {
    // As soon as the user stops touching the slide, releases it, start the automatic sliding again
    startInterval();
  };

  const carouselImages = [
    {url: 'https://i.ibb.co/FDwNR9d/img1.jpg'},
    {url: 'https://i.ibb.co/7G5qqGY/1.jpg'},
    {url: 'https://i.ibb.co/Jx7xqf4/pexels-august-de-richelieu-4427816.jpg'},
    {url: 'https://i.ibb.co/GV08J9f/pexels-pixabay-267202.jpg'},
    {url: 'https://i.ibb.co/sK92ZhC/pexels-karolina-grabowska-4210860.jpg'},
  ];

  const setIndex = event => {
    let viewSize = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width;
    let contentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    let carouselIndex = Math.floor(contentOffset / viewSize);
    setSelectedIndex(carouselIndex);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{width: dimension.width}}>
      <ScrollView
        horizontal
        ref={scrollRef}
        onMomentumScrollEnd={setIndex}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        onTouchStart={onTouchStart}
        onTouchEnd={onTouchEnd}
        pagingEnabled>
        {carouselImages.map((value, key) => (
          <Image
            source={{uri: `${value.url}`}}
            style={{width: dimension?.width, height: 250, resizeMode: 'cover'}}
            PlaceholderContent={<ActivityIndicator />}
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0,
          alignSelf: 'center',
        }}>
        {carouselImages.map((val, key) => (
          <Text
            key={key}
            style={key === selectedIndex ? {color: 'white'} : {color: '#888'}}>
            ⬤
          </Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default HomeCarousel;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your images aren't being update because of 2 things:

1. You're setting the update in an anonymous function which isn't being called:

```
// You're just defining the function here and not actually calling it
() => {
  scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
    animated: true,
    y: 0,
    x: dimension.width * selectedIndex,
  });
};
```

2. Your `useEffect` doesn't have any dependencies, which means its callback won't be changed, and therefore the `selectedIndex` inside of it will always be 0:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    setSelectedIndex(prevSelectedIndex =>
      prevSelectedIndex === carouselImages.length - 1
        ? 0
        : prevSelectedIndex + 1,
    );
    () => {
      scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
        animated: true,
        y: 0,
        // Since there are no dependencies, this callback won't ever be changed and selectedIndex will always be 0
        x: dimension.width * selectedIndex,
      });
    };
  }, 3000);
  // You have no dependencies here
}, []);
```

My suggestions for improvements/fixes would be:

1. Extract the function to update the slides out of `useEffect` callback and apply a `useCallback` hook with `selectedIndex` dependency. You should also calculate the value of the new index outside of the `setSelectedIndex` hook, because [`setState/useState` doesn't update immediately](https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately):

```
// You should also use an intervalId so that you can clear the interval/reset when needed
let intervalId = null;

const HomeCarousel = () => {
  // ... rest of the HomeCarousel component

  const onSlideChange = useCallback(() => {
    // Calculate newIndex here and use it to update your state and to scroll to the new slide
    const newIndex = selectedIndex === carouselImages.length - 1 ? 0 : selectedIndex + 1;

    setSelectedIndex(newIndex);

    scrollRef?.current?.scrollTo({
      animated: true,
      y: 0,
      x: dimension.width * newIndex,
    });
  }, [selectedIndex]);

  const startInterval = useCallback(() => {
    intervalId = setInterval(onSlideChange, 3000);
  }, [onSlideChange]);

  useEffect(() => {
    startInterval();

    return () => {
      // Clear the interval when component unmounts, otherwise you could have memory leaks
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, [onSlideChange]);  

  // ... rest of the HomeCarousel component
};
```

2. Another thing I would suggest you to make this carousel complete is to clear the interval/stop the automatic sliding as soon as the user starts sliding, otherwise it would cause weird behavior and slides getting out of control. You can restart the automatic sliding as soon as the user has finished his sliding action:

```
const onTouchStart = () => {
  // As soon as the user touches the slide, stop the automatic sliding
  clearInterval(intervalId);
};

const onTouchEnd = () => {
  // As soon as the user stops touching the slide, releases it, start the automatic sliding again
  startInterval();
};

return (
  <ScrollView
    // ... Other scrollview props
    onTouchStart={onTouchStart}
    onTouchEnd={onTouchEnd}>
    {/* ... Rest of the component */}
```

Comment: man you are genius!!!!
working perfectly as I wanted

Comment: how do accept the answer?
Also the carousel works good however I am trying to modify one thing that is, when the carousel comes to the last image it slides to the first image displaying al the images in fraction of the second. To be more clear, I am looking for smthng like infinite scroll

Comment: You accept the answer by ticking the check mark below the votes of the answer, like shown on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)
I am not quite sure how you could achieve your desired behavior

Answer (score 0):

```js
const carouselImages = [
    carousel1,
    carousel2,
    carousel3,
    carousel4,
    carousel5
];

const Carousel = () => {
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const next = (current + 1) % carouselImages.length;
            
        const id = setTimeout(() => setCurrent(next), 3000);
        return () => clearTimeout(id);
    }, [current]);
    return (
        <div className="banner">
            <div className="slider">
                <img src={carouselImages[current]} alt="carousel" />
            </div>
            <div className="overlay"></div>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).